# How do you move your Git repository from one server to another?

Tags: git

I need to move Git to a new location and was wondering if there's a way to just rsync my git repository to a new location?

Answer (score 11):

rsync, or just clone, as git clones are complete copies of (the reachable parts of) the source repository.

Comment: `git-clone` would be safer. To use `rsync` you would need to stop _all_ other access to the repository first to ensure `rsync` can produce a consistent copy at the other end.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
git remote add servername master
git push servername master
```

Replace servername by you new git repository

Answer (score 0):

I am no git expert, but where do you see the problem in doing exactly that? Of course, you will need to inform the users about this change and if it's not your machine, talk to the admin to set up the server part, but other than that, git repos are just directories with some (or a lot) files.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `scp -r` will do the trick just fine.